# перестали работать обработчики событий в Андроиде

Tags: android-intent, android-on-click, setonclicklistener, onclicklistener

Есть фрагмент:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.dimab.iternerary.Taxi">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im_taxi_activity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                android:src="@drawable/taxi_activity" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_taxi_kiev"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/im_taxi_activity"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/the_provision_of_taxi" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_uber"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textview_taxi_kiev"
                android:text="@string/uber"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/uber_call"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textview_uber"
                android:text="@string/call" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/uber_download"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/uber_call"
                android:text="@string/download" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_uklon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/uber_download"
                android:text="@string/uklon"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/uklon_download"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/textview_uklon"
                android:text="@string/download" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/uklon_order_online"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/uklon_download"
                android:text="@string/order_online" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_taxi_plus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/uklon_order_online"
                android:text="@string/taxi_plus"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/taxi_plus_call"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/textview_taxi_plus"
                android:text="@string/call" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/taxi_plus_order_online"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/taxi_plus_call"
                android:text="@string/order_online" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/taxi_plus_download"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/taxi_plus_order_online"
                android:text="@string/download" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

И есть класс к ниму:

```
package com.example.dimab.iternerary;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


public class Taxi extends Fragment {


    Button uber_call;
    Button uber_download;
    Button uklon_download;
    Button uklon_order_online;
    Button taxi_plus_call;
    Button taxi_plus_order_online;
    Button taxi_plus_download;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_taxi, null);

        uber_call = v.findViewById(R.id.uber_call);
        uber_download = v.findViewById(R.id.uber_download);
        uklon_download = v.findViewById(R.id.uklon_download);
        uklon_order_online = v.findViewById(R.id.uklon_order_online);        taxi_plus_call = v.findViewById(R.id.taxi_plus_call);
        taxi_plus_order_online = v.findViewById(R.id.taxi_plus_order_online);
        taxi_plus_download = v.findViewById(R.id.taxi_plus_download);

        View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (getId()) {
                    case R.id.uber_call:
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:9988")), "Call"));
                        break;
                    case R.id.uber_download:
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ubercab&hl=en")), "Browser"));
                        break;
                    case R.id.uklon_download:
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ua.com.uklontaxi&hl=en")), "Browser"));
                        break;
                    case R.id.uklon_order_online:
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.uklon.com.ua/")), "Browser"));
                        break;
                    case R.id.taxi_plus_call:
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:244")), "Call"));
                        break;
                    case R.id.taxi_plus_order_online:
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://taxiplus.ua/")), "Browser"));
                        break;
                    case R.id.taxi_plus_download:
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sss.taxi.plus")), "Browser"));
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        uber_call.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        uber_download.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        uklon_download.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        uklon_order_online.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        taxi_plus_call.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        taxi_plus_order_online.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        taxi_plus_download.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

        return v;

    }
}
```

В классе перестали работать обработчики событий, никаких манипуляций с кодом не делал. Есть похоже класс, написаный точно так же, и там всё работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в операторе `switch` вместо `getId()`снадо вписать `view.getId()` так как это класс наследуемый от фрагмента